# blank "key" output on python encryption file

Tags: python, encryption, key

I'm writing a program, and am having some difficulty. My software encodes files, and outputs a file called `keys.txt`, and reads in files to encrypt from a text file called `emergency_encrypt.txt`. The problem is that when I run the program, I get a blank key file and the files in `emergenc_encrypt.txt` aren't encrypted.
Here is the code for the program:

```
import random

characters = ["a", 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
              'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
              'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '`',
              '~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '=', '+', '[', '{', ']', '}', '|', ';',
              ":", '\"', "'", '<', '.', '>', '/', "?"]

def fileEncrypter(filename):
    with open(filename) as myfile:
        data = myfile.read()

    random.seed
    encrypted = ""
    key = ""
    i = 0

    while(i < len(data)):
        bl = random.randint(1, 500)
        buffer = ""
        a = 0
        while(a < len(bl)):
            charnum = random.randint(0, len(characters) - 1)
            char = characters[charnum]
            buffer = buffer + char
            a = a + 1

        char = data[i]
        encrypted = buffer + char
        key = key + str(bl) + "-"

    x = len(key) - 2
    key = key[:x]
    data = [encrypted, key]

def setEncrypter(root):
    with open("emergency_encrypt.txt") as myfile:
        fileset = myfile.read().split("\n")

    i = 0
    file = open("keys.txt", "w+")
    while(i < len(fileset)):
        filein = fileset[i]
        data = fileEncrypter(filein)
        file = open(filein, "w+")
        dataout = filein + ";" + data[1]
        with open(filein, "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(data[0])
        with open("keys.txt", "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(dataout + "\n")
        i = i + 1

print "Enter the Designated Key Device (DKD) Address:"
root = raw_input("@> ")
setEncrypter(root)
```

Comment: `random.seed` in `fileEncrypter` isn't doing anything. It's a function, you need to call it.

Comment: Does this code actually run for you? The comparison `a < len(bl)` raises an exception, as `bl` is an `int` and has no `__len__`.

Comment: In `setEncrypter` you have `data = fileEncrypter(filein)` but `fileEncrypter` doesn't return anything, so your code will fail on the subsequent lines which attempt to subscript it.